# Woocommerce sidebar widget categories sorting not working

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, categories

I displayed **Woocommerce categories widget** in sidebar of product archive page. And I tried following code to sort categories in sidebar.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'custom_woocommerce_product_subcategories_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_product_subcategories_args( $args ) {
    $args['menu_order'] = 'asc';
    return $args;
}
```

I want to sort categories and sub-categories both, But is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can say all **Product Categories** of `Woo Commerce` is by default sorted by `Product Names` in `ascending` order in **Product Categories** widget. You can use it in any page (e.g. Product landing page, product-single page, archive page etc).

You just need to use **Product Categories** widget in your sidebar. That's it...